# How to resolve symbols from memory addresses in nt.sys and w32k.sys

Tags: windows, system-calls, etw

In the 64 bit editions of Windows 7/8/2012, the ETW kernel tracer provides memory addresses for system call enter events.  I would like to map these addresses to something meaningful, like the name of the function that lives at that address:  e.g. AcceptConnectPort.

I know I can use `ln` (List Nearest Symbols) in a kernel debugger session to lookup the symbols at a particular address.  What I desire is a way do do this *programmatically*.  Is there a library I can use to look up a symbol at a given a memory address?

Better yet, is there an authoritative reference for the memory offsets for different Windows versions.  I found [this table](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi_64/), but those numbers don't appear to correspond to any of the memory addresses I have observed.

Comment: have you looked at Dependency Walker (depends.exe) Home Page
www.dependencywalker.com

Comment: You can use the DbgHelp library to fetch the appropriate symbols from the Microsoft symbol server and do lookups - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It is doubtful that there is any published list (official or unofficial) of function addresses. It would be massive, as the addresses in a module can change every time a Windows update occurs.

Comment: @Marichyasana Dependency Walker looks promising, but the entry points shown in the program do not appear to correspond to any of the offsets I observed in the kernel traces.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I think DbgHelp is the key here.  Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I've worked on a project that needed to do this. We used the DbgHelp API that Andrew mentioned in his comment to download the relevant `.PDB` files and to look in them for the offsets we needed.

I've since moved on, so I don't have access to look at the source code for that project, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: This looks useful, but the code I am working with is written in C#.  Looks like I will have some work to do to interface with the API.

Comment: As it turns out, there is also a command line interface for DebugHelp, [dbg.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is included with the Windows debug tools.